# Is there a way to increase the duration of an exit transition?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation, transition

I've been using transitions to create some cool animations when entering and exiting an Activity. But I'm having trouble increasing the duration of the exit animation. Is this even possible? Currently I have tried this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And I've also tried this. but it doesn't seem to work

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode().setDuration(2000));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Explode exitTransition = new Explode();
exitTransition.setDuration(2000);
getWindow().setExitTransition(exitTransition);
```

**Hope this answer helped!**